# Video HTML5 não executando no mobile

Tags: html, css, vídeo

Estou criando um projeto na qual tenho um video rolando na página em background, na versão desktop está funcionando perfeitamente, mas no mobile o video não executa e fica apenas a tela azul (div que coloquei para dar um opacity no video).

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted>
 <source src="expo.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Servidor de teste: https://cliente.creativecode.art.br/expotattoo.html

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Na versão mobile ou no celular?

Comment: Celular, ou mobile, acho que dá na mesma né

Comment: não... vc pode abrir a versão mobile no desktop

Comment: Enfim, no cel não tá indo

Answer (score 1):

Conforme respondido **[aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267513/8063)**, dispositivos móveis não rodam vídeos em *background*. É interessante incluir o atributo `poster` na tag `<video>`, que irá mostrar uma imagem estática no lugar do vídeo.

Para que o fundo não fique apenas com uma cor, coloque em `poster` uma imagem relacionada ao vídeo:

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted poster="imagem.jpg">
```